# Local function definitions are illegal

Tags: c++

Below is some of my C++ code. I'm getting this error:

> C2601: 'main' : local function definitions are illegal

Why do I get this?

```
BOOL CBasicApp::InitInstance()
{
    typedef BOOL (__stdcall *pFunc) ();

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        pFunc pf = 0;

        HMODULE hMod = 0;

        hMod = LoadLibrary("dbgghelp.dll");

        if (!hMod)
        {
            printf("File not found: Dbgghelp.DLL\n");
            return 0;

        }

        pf = GetProcAddress(hMod,"L100A6F95");
```

Comment: Try moving the typedef out the method. Either put it in the .h file or after the imports.

Comment: I think the error message is quite clear. In C++ you can't define a function locally (i.e. directly within another function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main` is the entry point function for a console app.  It must be in global scope.  You cant nest functions inside of other functions anyway.

Try something more like this instead:

```
BOOL CBasicApp::InitInstance()
{
    typedef BOOL (__stdcall *pFunc)();

    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("dbgghelp.dll");
    if (!hMod)
    {
        printf("Error loading dbgghelp.DLL\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    pFunc pf = GetProcAddress(hMod, "L100A6F95");
    if (!pf)
    {
        printf("Error finding L100A6F95 function\n");
        FreeLibrary(hMod);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!pf())
    {
        printf("L100A6F95 function failed\n");
        FreeLibrary(hMod);
        return FALSE;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return TRUE;
}

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CBasicApp app;
    if (app.InitInstance())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the `main` function out of the `InitInstance` function body.

In C++, it's not possible to define nested functions inside of other functions (except for lambda functions, but they are expressions, not function definitions).

Answer (score 0):

thanks buddies to all who comment and help ..fixed by just added to my .h/header file the code

```
typedef BOOL (__stdcall *pFunc) ();
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

below my

```
public:
virtual BOOL InitInstance();`
```

then its successfull compile no error...but now my problem is why my mainapp.exe not execute when im launching the launcher btw my dgghelp.dll was a game protection for using ce,macro and other i just rename it...it has some i guess dumps code inside....